# Adding search terms: (Failed) attempt to add invisible text

Tags: discussion, search

I have just edited [Backquotes in titles](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/991/4330) here on meta. I did this, because I knew this Q&A existed, but the search [title+backtick](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=title+backtick) did not find the result. I was hoping to edit it in such a way that the search would find it.

I have thought about this problem before, but this time I finally edited in a html comment to see if that helped with the search. The html comment is invisible in the text, so if that would work, I thought that would be ideal. Unfortunately it did not. The comment is still present in the body of the question, but search above does not find the question. Google also doesn't find it: [search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=site%3A+meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com+title+backtick&oq=site%3A+meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com+title+backtick&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i58.7005j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=site:+meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com+title+backtick), but with backquote instead of backtick it is the first result. Strange that google didn't find it btw, they are synonyms and google keeps track of synonyms. Also I think similar searches where you search for visible text in the question body does yield the desired result.

Other methods to help with searches could be the following. I have seen a comment, I think by ssch, to help with searches in a particular Q&A. Lastly, a drastic method to resolve the backtick vs backquote problem would be to always use backtick instead of backquote and to leave a note on the site somewhere that we all do so, but even if we make that big effort it is not ideal.

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions/thoughts on how to add search terms.

*Search terms: apostrophe, quote, grave accent*

Comment: The question leaves little room for an interesting answer, as it seems reasonable to assume at this point that there is no technique w.r.t. adding search terms (being applied) that is not covered in the question. Possibly meta.so has some related threads.

Comment: Hey at least I got the tumbleweed badge for this :P